# How to fix error "Could not establish FTP connection, invalid host or port" in Magento

Tags: magento, ftp, magento-1.9, dataflow

I am trying to import products into Magento from a remote FTP server using Magento's Advanced Dataflow Profile but I keep getting the error below. I am new to this and could not find an answer anywhere on how to fix this and am hoping someone can help me fix this issue. The info I found on "To load data from remote FTP server" does not seem to work for me.

Error when running import:

> Starting Mage_Dataflow_Model_Convert_Adapter_Io :: load
>   An error occurred while opening file: "Could not establish FTP connection, invalid host or port".

Actions XML code I am using:

```xml
<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="load">
    <var name="type">ftp</var>
    <var name="host"><![CDATA[ftp://000.00.00.00]]></var>
    <var name="passive">true</var>
    <var name="user"><![CDATA[USER]]></var>
    <var name="password"><![CDATA[PWD]]></var>
<var name="path"><![CDATA[/]]></var>
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[feed.csv]]></var>
    <var name="format"><![CDATA[csv]]></var>
</action>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `host` parameter is for host name (or IP address).

What you have entered is not a host name, but an FTP URL. The hostname (or actually the IP address) is the "000.00.00.00".